# SqlConnection vs Sql Session. Do their lifetimes coincide?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, connection-pooling

I want to apply some sql-session level settings for certain processes in my `c#` app.

For instance, I want to set `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY` for some background processes to `LOW`.

The questions are:

1. If I open a new sql connection, does that start a new sql-session?
2. Will the sql-session live until the connection is closed? If I apply my settings right after the `SqlConnection` is opened, will they be valid for all queries executed in context of that same `SqlConnection`?
3. What about **connection pooling**? Is this possible that my `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW` setting will be reused by other processes in my system (which I don't want to) because the `SqlConnection` is not actually closed ( **asp.net connection pooling** decides to reuse it).

Thank you!

Comment: From what I remember, a `session` will show external connections and internal processes, and a `connection` will only show external connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADO.NET executes `sp_reset_connection` when you take a `SqlConnection` from the pool (after having closed it so that it gets returned to the pool). According to [What does "exec sp_reset_connection" mean in Sql Server Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641120/what-exec-sp-reset-connection-shown-in-sql-profiler-means) all `SET` options are being reset. That would include `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY`.

I would still suggest that you write a tiny test program to confirm this. ADO.NET session pooling is not perfect, for example it does not reset the `ISOLATION LEVEL` and does not rollback transactions when closing.

Comment: Thank you! That was rather useful. Could you please answer the first 2 questions as well? I guess the answer is "Yes" for both?

Comment: The `SqlConnection` really represents a session for SQL Server. The physical connection is managed by ADO.NET. Whenever you `Open` a `SqlConnection` you create a new session, not a new connection. So: 1 = yes, 2 = yes, 3 = no (but beware of `ISOLATION LEVEL`! - I consider this to be a bug).

Comment: Note: `sp_reset_connection` is (unfortunately?) called when *acquiring* a connection from a pool, not *releasing* a connection. This can lead to 'odd session stuff' between the two actions, including Session sp_getapplocks not being released :}