# IIS SQL Server: Connection Pool: Why are new connections made instead of reusing existing connections?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis, connection-pooling

During app loading a single user will add 10 connections to the pool. Then if I load another user I will have a total of 20 connections.

Why are new connections being added to the pool instead of reusing connections? I can see that that there are connections available that haven't been used in minutes yet it still opens new connections.

- Its the same connection string
- I ran SQL Sever Profiler I can see sp_reset_connection being called after every call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641120/what-exec-sp-reset-connection-shown-in-sql-profiler-means) might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the connections are coming from a different machine, the connections can't be pooled. A connection required both endpoints to be a connection. If you are using connection pooling correctly, applications instantiate a connection (from the pool), use the connection, then drop it as soon as exchange is complete.

If you a writing a single-threaded desktop app, another common and simple strategy is to open a connection, and just leave that connection open as long as the application is running.

You can control how many connections are created, etc.  see [MS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) for more details related to connection pooling.

IIRC, connection pools are not shared unless the connection string is identical either.