# Glimpse Sql Tab Connections and DbContext instants

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, glimpse

in an action I've instantiated my `DbContext` through a using block:

```
using(var context = new DbContext())
{
    //EF codes
}
```

inside the block, I'm making several queries to the database. I thought that `using block` opens **one** connection and all queries use the same one connection.

but then I added `Glimpse` and I see that there are `7 connections` not one! and no `Transactions`.

[image]

what is wrong? did I misunderstand the DbContext behavior? or what ?

**Update:**

I just checked it with `ExpressProfiler` and this is the result. after each `command` there is a `sp_reset_connection`.

**Note :** `PSID` is the same (52) for all commands.

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: what does sql profiler or https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ says ?

Comment: @tschmit007 : updated the question with ExpressProfiler

Comment: the SPID column would be great

Comment: @tschmit007 PSID is the same for all commands.

Comment: so there is only one connection and the information of Glimpse should be intepreted. By the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641120/what-exec-sp-reset-connection-shown-in-sql-profiler-means

Comment: Glimpse works by watching the underlying use of the Connections/Commands/etc at an ADO level. Hence, if its saying that there are 7 connections at play here, I would say with a largish degree of confidence that at least at an ADO level, 7 connections are being created. Why this is the case I'm not sure. I would be interested if this is the same in your test environment. The question in my mind is "Why is EF using multiple connections in the one context".