# why? connection reset by jdbc (ms sqlserver)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

- MS SQL Server 2008
- sqljdbc4.jar

Connection is OK. But if I execute any SQL or any string, just "connection reset" occurrs.

Why does this happen? I don't have any experiences for any dbms (oracle, mssql, etc...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846459/how-do-i-resolve-mssql-resetting-connections                 may help