# Local temporary table(SQL Server) not dropping automatically after method execution with JdbcTemplate but works with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Tags: sql-server, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate, namedparameterjdbctemplate

I am trying to execute a native query in which I've created local temporary table. My front end call an Api and a method executes that query. If I call that method again, sometimes i get, object(#temptablename) already present in database, if i keep refreshing my front end, 1 out 10 times it works.

This is much simplified form of complex query, but you will get the gist of what i'm trying to do.

```
select * into #ts from (
    "some select query"
) as tmp1;

Select
    *
from
    #ts
```

This method doesn't work every time.

jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);

This works every time.

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, args);

Args in case of namedParameterJdbcTemplate is garbage args as this query doesn't require any arguments.

My hunch is jdbcTemplate keeps using the same connection for every call because local temp table is associated with connection and namedParameterJdbcTemplate creates new connection every time.

How I created data source inside @PostConstruct method

```
DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().username(username).password(password)
                            .url(url + ";ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly").build();
jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Comment: A temporary table is automatically dropped after the scope that created it ends; this sounds like you are using a single persistent connection, and so the temporary table *isn't* dropped because the scope doesn't end.

Comment: No, i am not creating any connection by myself, connections are managed by spring itself. I've set datasource in both object namedJdbc and plain jdbc template. If i return data to the front end scope that created it is over.

Comment: this is pretty bad, it should call sp_reset_connection so the tables are properly dropped (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641120/what-does-exec-sp-reset-connection-mean-in-sql-server-profiler) if it uses a pool. i'm guessing though your settings are wrong because otherwise a lot more people would have this issue. Perhaps you try to use some generic jdbc setting so it doesn't know about microsoft specific stuff?

Comment: you can read some stuff here: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/1861 as well

Comment: Please show what datasource you are using and how youa re calling this code. and no the scope isn't over especially if you use a connection pool, the connection is simply returned to the pool.

Comment: Have you considered prepending your current query with `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ts;` or, better, appending it with `DROP TABLE #ts;`?

Comment: @siggemannen i myself haven't faced this problem till today because every query that i was using earlier had arguments so every time i ended up using namedParameterJdbcTemplate this time i don't needed arguments so i used jdbcTemplate. That is why i faced this issue. I have hundreds of query which uses temp table but this query is first time i faced the issue.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes i am using drop table as quick fix on my live environment. I am just curious why it isn't working.

Comment: @M.Deinum edited my original post with data source creation code

Comment: @siggemannen The link you shared explains a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you creating your own `DataSource`. You are using Spring Boot (judging from the classes in use) so just inject it (as well as use the pre-configured `JdbcTEmplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. It doesn't make sense as the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is just a wrapper around the regular `JdbcTemplate` which does some String munging (replace placeholders) before calling the `JdbcTemplate` methods.